# Get database data in non-normalized format

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Volunteers (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    phoneNumber varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
)

CREATE TABLE Lists (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    listName varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
CREATE TABLE VolunteerLists(
    list int(11) NOT NULL,
    volunteer int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (list,volunteer),
    FOREIGN KEY (list) REFERENCES Lists(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (volunteer) REFERENCES Volunteers(id),
)
```

Then I have in volunteers table:

```
1, David, 555-5555555
2, Joe, 444-4444444
```

in the lists table:

```
1, visitors
2, deliveries
3, cleaning
```

in the VolunteerLists table:

```
1,1
1,2
2,1
2,3
```

How can I get my data in the following format:

```
VolunteerID   VolunteerName  visitors deliveries cleaning 
1             David          TRUE      TRUE       FALSE
2             Joe            TRUE      FALSE      TRUE
```

I know I can use a left Join to get this if I know the list ids, but the lists are dynamic and I don't want to hardcode this.
I can query the database to get the lists, and then build the query in php based on that, but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You should add sample data to your question.  I can't figure out what you want here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sample data added

Comment: What's the connection between `ListA`, `ListB`, `ListC`, and your sample data?

Answer (score 0):

This just looks like a basic pivot query to me:

```
SELECT
    v.id AS VolunteerID,
    v.name AS VolunteerName,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(l.listName = 'visitors') > 0
         THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS visitors,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(l.listName = 'deliveries') > 0
         THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS deliveries,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(l.listName = 'cleaning') > 0
         THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS cleaning
FROM Volunteers v
INNER JOIN VolunteerLists vl
    ON v.id = vl.volunteer
INNER JOIN Lists l
    ON vl.list = l.id
GROUP BY
    v.id,
    v.name;
```

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to do this without knowing in advance the names, or even how many, lists there are?

Comment: Not knowing the list names (but knowing their numbers), yes.  Not knowing the number of lists, then no, not without using dynamic SQL, which would need some fairly ugly code.

Comment: So if I don't know the number of lists, my best option would be to first retrieve that info with php or whatever and build this type of query progmatically over there?

Comment: Or create a proc/function in MySQL which does the heavy lifting.

Comment: In any case, this query does not seem to work.  I'm getting true in all fields